# Domain user does not have local rights

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, windows-server-2003

The domain controller is running windows server 2003. The workstation in question has a fresh install of windows 7, with only a local administrator account. The workstation is joined to the domain. I have added his domain user to the local machine as a standard user. Upon logging in with his domain user, he does not have access to any locally installed programs,drives, printers etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add him as a local administrator rather than a standard user, then once logged in - change it back afterwards. Remember that Windows 2003 server is no longer supported and server 2008r2 is far less problematic.